# In a Oracle Schema I want to know how many Tables, Procedures, Functions are there? How to find?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In a Oracle Schema I want to know how many Tables, Procedures, Functions are there? How to find?

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

Comment: Do you want tables created by users, system tables, or both?

Comment: I want to know how to find the schema objects?. can i find using a query?

Comment: Select * from dba_objects 
   Where schema_name = 'TEST' 
   and object_type in ('PROCEDURE',’TABLE’,'PACKAGE','FUNCTION','PACKAGE BODY' )                                                                                                                                  
can i use this query?

Comment: You no need to provide schema name if you are in particular user in the database

Comment: Is it a same schema?

Comment: Another question for you......Select rownum, a.* from hr.employees a order by salary. Will rownum will be 1,2,3?

Comment: @Prdp - this is Oracle, not MySQL.

Comment: @Vamshi - please open a new thread if you have an unrelated question.

Comment: Can't you answer here. Because I am not able to open a new thread

Comment: I meant your "where is [rownum](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns009.htm) documented?" question has nothing to do with your "where are the [data dictionary views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_1158.htm) documented?" question.

Comment: Can i ask you one small question?, if you don't mind!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL developer which gives you a very good GUI interface for oracle database. But still you want it from database you can use below queries,

> For tables,

```
SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES; - Provides you details of all tables and user of that table
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES; - Provides you details of Current user. It dosen't have owner column
```

> For Procedures, functions and pakages

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN('FUNCTION','PROCEDURE','PACKAGE')
```

> If you want to find the count of rocedures, functions and pakages

```
SELECT OBJECT_TYPE, COUNT(*) FROM ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN('FUNCTION','PROCEDURE','PACKAGE')
GROUP BY OBJECT_TYPEIN
```

> SQL developer link
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. can you be more specific with details.

Comment: Download SQL developer application. Install it and associate your database with that application and you can have your details. If you are stuck while associating database to sql developer, just let me know will help you. First install SQL developer

Comment: Can i use this query?                                                                                   Select * from dba_objects 
   Where schema_name = 'TEST' 
   and object_type in ('PROCEDURE',’TABLE’,''FUNCTION',)

Comment: Check the query i provided you

Comment: Can't I use dba_objects instead of all_objects?

Comment: I need within the schema

Comment: dba_objects provides your required data for your root user or dba user. If you use all_objects, it gives you all the PROCEDURES or FUNCTIONS in entire database. Using owner name you can find in which user those PROCEDURES or FUNCTIONS of TABLES created

Comment: so what is your database name?

Comment: Schema name 'DV303', DataBase Name 'TASDEV'

Comment: Thats why am telling you you can use sql developer which reduces querying your dba things. If you need it you can download it from the link provided in the answer

Comment: Sure Thankyou so much. Also I have few more questions?. do you mind asking you?

Comment: No not at all buddy. You can ask me. My pleasure to answer you

Comment: Having two schemas A and B. In both the schemas having table called TEST. Having Procedure in Schema A called insert_test which will insert row into the table TEST. Calling this procedure from Schema B. Now in which schema record will be inserted?

Comment: i have an interview tomorrow. i need to prepare these questions. Please dont mind.

Comment: Very nice question. Don't worry i ll answer you

Comment: No it will not work. In order to execute your procedure in the first schema use the query ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = schema. This will point your another schema and executes the procedure. Ok first of all, do you under stand what is schema?

Comment: Yes,I do. Schema is set of objects connected to an database user.

Comment: Good. Its in technical way. What is your opinion on schema. You can say in you native language as well. Just memorizing the definition will not guide you

Comment: Ok hope now you ll understand. See schema is a memory location. All the tables, each and every attributes of a database is stores in a file. Using SQL query, data is retrieved. The file store in a specification location is known as schema. Multiple schemas (i.e, files in different locations)  can be created to make our data secure or unique

Comment: Schema is a place where you will connect to the database using the credentials provided to the user.

Comment: So, what is the answer to my question??   Having two schemas A and B. In both the schemas having table called TEST. Having Procedure in Schema A called insert_test which will insert row into the table TEST. Calling this procedure from Schema B. Now in which schema record will be inserted?

Comment: No Schema is the memory location where your data is stored. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, I understood the actual meaning of Schema.

Comment: It is not possible to call stored procedure from one schema to another. Instead you can alter your current session and call the procedure. You can achieve using the query **ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = schema**

Comment: Got it. Thankyou.  Few more questions?

Comment: Sure buddy. Ask what ever doubt you have

Comment: I want to load 20 million rows into a table from another table. Both the structure are same. What is the fastest Method? What are the steps you will take before loading?

Comment: have answered you buddy

Comment: Do you mind asking you another question?

Comment: @JimMacaulay - a schema is not a "memory location", it is a set of related database objects, or a namespace for database objects, or an account that owns database objects, depending on your point of view. Table definitions are not "stored in a file". It is completely possible to call another schema's procedures. `ALL_OBJECTS` does not give you all the procedures or functions in the entire database.

Comment: Yes William i agree with you. I am not mentioning the location as a schema. The attributes assigned for a database is considered as a schema. To make understand Vamshi, answer was provided in a simple way as he is a beginer in DBA related stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

> To insert into another table which has same structure use,

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: What are the steps you will take before loading?

Comment: Steps in the sense? See you can directly insert into the table which hase same structure. Can you explain what you meant to say steps?

Comment: If we are inserting million records from another table. Just to make sure that we dont loose anything. So before inserting do we need to follow any specific rules or conditions. just to make we dont mess up with the data

Comment: You are selecting and inserting data. So here no data loss will be occurs. Your are just selecting and inserting the data

Comment: Ok. Thanks Again  
                                                                                                
Assume that there are 3 rows in a employee table. Salaries are NULL, 12000 and 10000. When sum (salary). What will be the output? NULL or 22000.

Comment: This is another question.

Comment: My answer is 22000. am i right?

Comment: Your result will be 22000. NULL will be considered as 0. If you find you are gaining some knowledge, kindly vote for two of the answers provided

Comment: Yeah its right buddy

Comment: why NULL is considered as zero?

Comment: In a numeric data type column null values are considered as nothing. Since nothing will be a zero

Comment: Select rownum, a.* from hr.employees a order by salary. Will rownum will be 1,2,3?